# How to use class variables in object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

suppose I have a class in typescript file like below:

```
export class app {
  public variable1: string;
  public variable2: number;
  public variable3 = "Hello world"
  constructor(count: number) {
      this.variable1 = "something",
      this.variable2 = 1 + count;
   }

}
```

now in another file, I am exporting this class as:

```
import { app } from './directory';
let pageApp:app;
```

now, how can I access `app` variables here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your definition of the class is syntactically incorrect, no `let` in classes and semantically incorrect, you need to declare all fields:

```
// appClass.ts
export class app {
    variable1: string // implicitly public in typescript
    variable2: number
    variable3 = "Hellow world"
    constructor(count : number) {
        this.variable1 = "something";
        this.variable2 = 1 + count;
    }

}
```

With regard to usage, the import should be fine, but you need to import the file in which the class resides (not the directory as your imports suggest) and you need to new up the class to create an instance

```
import { app } from './appClass'; // notice no extension (no .js or .ts)
let pageApp:app = new app(1);
console.log(pageApp.variable2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Reference    --> [Typescript classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Let's say you class as:

```
export class app {
   //you can specify Public, private, and protected modifiers
   // default consider as public so you can access in other class as well.

   public variable1="Hellow world";
   public variable2: any
   public variable3: any;

  constructor(count){
      this.variable1="something",
      this.variable2=1+count;
   }
}
```

import in another file

```
import { app } from './directory';
let var_name = new app('pass_count_here')

//Access
var_name.variable1
```

Comment: I found your solution the most useful. Just a heads up - if you are writing TypeScript >4 or Angular >9, there is no need for the public modifier.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, the term *class variable* is used for variables which are *class members*, i.e. variables that live on the class, but not on the instance. That means, they exist before any instance has been constructed.

In TypeScript, these class variables are created with the `static` keyword. (This is the reason, why they are also called *static methods*.) In your example, only `variable1` could be made a class variable, because the other two variables are *instance members* (also called *instance variables*), because they get their value during instantiation - in the `constructor` method.

In order to make `variable1` a class method, make it `static`, like so:

```js
export class app {
   static variable1 = "Hello, World";

   public variable2: any;
   public variable3: any;

  constructor(count){
      this.variable1 = "something";
      this.variable2 = 1 + count;
   }
}
```

Now, it can be addressed from the class`app`, without any instantiation:

```js
console.log(app.variable1)  // Hello, World
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the methods and variables of class A in File 1 from File 2 by creating it object

Here is a short example for you

**File 1: App.ts**

```
export class App {

variable1: string;
variable2: number;


constructor(count){
    this.variable1="something";
    this.variable2= 1 + count;
 }
```

}

**File 2: File2.ts**

```
import {App} from './App';
console.log("Hello ", new App(2).variable1);
```

It will work fine. Similarly, you can do with the methods of the class too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate the class let instance = new App(1)

you can implement a getter inside your class

```
public getVariable(){
  return variable1;
}
```

or you can just declare the variables as public

```
public variable1;
```